# How to request this URL and real the content of response using PHP?

Tags: php, http, rest, xmlhttprequest

I want to request this URL `translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=t&text=hello&hl=en&sl=en&tl=ar&multires=1&oc=3&prev=btn&ssel=0&tsel=0&sc=1`

using `PHP` and reading the response. How ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Google Translate API](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/language/translate/overview.html) instead of requesting an HTML page and parsing the HTML.

Sample:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=YOUR-API-KEY&source=en&target=de&q=Your%20text
```

Comment: "Important: Google Translate API v2 is now available as a paid service. The courtesy limit for existing Translate API v2 projects created prior to August 24, 2011 will be reduced to zero on December 1, 2011. In addition, the number of requests your application can make per day will be limited. Google Translate API v1 will be shut off completely on the same date (December 1, 2011);"

Comment: Thx, good to know. But if it is used by a commercial application I think $20.00 for 1 million characters might be worth the money...

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of options with [cURL](http://php.net/curl) and [readfile](http://php.net/readfile) being the obvious ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the file_get_contents() see http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

But it is not as efficient as other methods to read remote files.

ie)

```
$mytranslation = file_get_contents("translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=t&text=hello&hl=en&sl=en&tl=ar&multires=1&oc=3&prev=btn&ssel=0&tsel=0&sc=1");
```